# Can python function be called by a SQL server trigger?

Tags: python, sql-server-2008

I have a database in MS SQL Server 2008 that has 3 tables. I want to create a trigger for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE for each row for these tables. For the trigger function I want to call a python function. The python script needs to write some of the columns from the row for which the trigger occurred and write it to a socket. I checked on the net but could not find how the python function can be called as a trigger function.

**Edit**: Or is there a way the trigger procedure in SQL can do this itself? Can it act as a TCP server and write the trigger data to the socket?

Answer (score 4):

As [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) you can attach some .NET methods in SQL triggers, and then use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) to code your trigger, but it will cost you in term of security and performance.

You can also use [Database Email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) which is able to send an email which the content of what you need to catch, and grab it elsewhere in your own mail server.

Comment: Is there a way the trigger function itself can do this? Can it work like a TCP server and keep posting the trigger data to the socket?